# How can I not have to wait for the MediaPlayer to finish in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm currently using a MediaPlayer to play a 1 second sound file. However, I can't replay it right afterwards; I have to wait a while, which I don't want to do. 
I want to be able to play the sound file right after I click the View.

Here's my code:

```
final TextView lowBongo = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.low_bongo);
final MediaPlayer lowBongoMP = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.low_bongo_sound);
lowBongo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{
    public void onClick(View v) {
        lowBongoMP.start();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
final TextView lowBongo = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.low_bongo);
    final MediaPlayer lowBongoMP = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.low_bongo_sound);
    lowBongo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View v) {
            lowBongoMP.seekTo(0); //Start Song From 0 second
            lowBongoMP.start();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Stop whenever the song is about to play

```
final TextView lowBongo = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.low_bongo);
    final MediaPlayer lowBongoMP = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.low_bongo_sound);
    lowBongo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View v) {
            lowBongoMP.stop(); //stop current song
            lowBongoMP.start();
        }
    });
```